# how can i do UIView animateWithDuration in viewDidLoad? ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation

**I try this in viewDidAppear but i have a one second of delay =( what can i do? for work in viewDidLoad?**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


            fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
            fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
            fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((720*M_PI)/360)];
            fullRotation.duration = 5;
            //  fullRotation.repeatCount = 1e10f;
            [_propImaCirculoCompleto.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];


}
```

Comment: Putting it in viewDidLoad is probably not what you want.  Try viewWillAppear.  Are you doing anything else when the view appears that might be taking a lot of cpu cycles?

Comment: Why are you using an animation block? Run all that code outside. And don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:]`. Even though it does nothing for standard `UIViewController` classes, it's good practice :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do any animation in `viewDidLoad` as the view won't have a superview yet so the animation is irrelevant.

A few thoughts on your code sample:

- You can use `viewDidAppear` as long as you want the animation every
  time the view appears, not just the first time it is presented.
- Using Core Animation within an animation block isn't necessary. Do one or the other.

**Suggestions**

If you are trying to animate the appearance of a view managed by a different view controller, the presenting controller is responsible for the animation. There are a few ways to implement this depending on your minimum supported version of iOS.

- In iOS 5+ you can use a custom container controller to present a child view controller with a defined animation.
- In iOS 7 you can use 'presentViewController:animated:completion' and specify a custom animation. You would then set the `transitioningDelegate` property and have the delegate provide the animator for the transition.

I don't have ready sample code for the above but that's what I would look at.

Comment: Ok if you have a code sample to accomplish this please help me hehehe

Answer (score -1):

Try to split Your animation by two 180 degree rotations. Seems that iOS 7 is lazy and wan't rotate by 360 :)

Comment: Thats because full rotation is zero rotation.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question